# Issue with number of arguments in __init__() while using Inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am a beginner trying to perform inheritance using Python. So I decided to practice the example programs from the book "Data Structures and Algorithms in Python" by Michael T. Goodrich.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class Progression:
    def __init__(self,start=0):
        self._current = start

    def _advanced(self):
        self._current += 1

    def __next__(self):
        if self._current is None:
            raise StopIteration()
        else:
            answer = self._current
            self._advanced()
            return answer

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def print_progression(self,n):
        print(' '.join(str(next(self)) for j in range(n)))


class ArithmeticProgression:
    def __init__(self,increment=1,start=0):
        super().__init__(start)
        self._increment = increment

    def _advance(self):
        self._current += self._increment

class GeometricProgression(Progression):

    def __init__(self,base=2,start=1):
        super().__init__(start)
        self._base = base

    def _advance(self):
        self._current *= self._base

class FibonacciProgression(Progression):
    def __init__(self,first=0,second=1):
        super().__init__(first)
        self._prev = second - first

    def _advance(self):
        self._prev, self._current = self._current,self._prev + self._current

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Default Progression: ')
    Progression().print_progression(10)

    print('Arithmetic progression with increment 5 and start 2:')
    ArithmeticProgression(5,2).print_progression(10)

    print('Geometric progression with default base:')
    GeometricProgression().print_progression(10)

    print('Geometric progression with increasing it to the power of 2')
    GeometricProgression(3).print_progression(10)

    print('Fibonacci progression with default start progression')
    FibonacciProgression().print_progression(10)

    print('Fibonacci progression with default start progression')
    FibonacciProgression(4,6).print_progression(10)
```

Here is the error:

```
Default Progression: 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Arithmetic progression with increment 5 and start 2:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "some location", line 61, in <module>
    ArithmeticProgression(5,2).print_progression(10)

  File "some location", line 33, in __init__
    super().__init__(start)

TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Here I am trying to check the super().**init**(start) of ArithmeticProgression but am getting very confused with the passing of elements in **init**() example. Any help will be appreciated. Also I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArithmeticProgression` does not inherit from Progression like `GeometricProgression` does. So there's no base class to call with `super()`.

Replace
`class ArithmeticProgression(Progression):` 
with
`class ArithmeticProgression:`

To make it short: you just forgot `(Progression)`

Comment: To add to this, there's also a typo in his `_advance` method in `Progression`.